# How to handle Deprecation in Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat

I am new to use Tomcat. I was using tomcat 7 and I found WebSocketServlet,  MessageInbound, WsOutbound... are deprecated. Where can I get some examples in tomcat 8 that are used to replace those? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Information about deprecated classes can usually be found in the [API](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/websocket/WebSocketServlet.html).

> **Class WebSocketServlet**
>
> ...
>
> "Deprecated.  Replaced by the JSR356 WebSocket 1.0 implementation and
>   will be removed in Tomcat 8.0.x."

Information about implementing a websocket in Tomcat 8 can be found in the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html).